# I am trying to write a matlab code to calculate the distance between two microphones

Tags: matlab

Settings:
A sound is played out of a speaker, two microphones are placed close to the speakers, one microphone is closer to the speaker than the other.

I have to write a matlab code to determine the **distance** between the microphones. The following code, creates the random sound, plays it out on the speakers and records the sound simultaneously(at the same time) with the two mics. `y` is going to contain two column of data. the first column is the input signal from mic1 and the second column is the input signal from mic2.

```
fs= 44100;     

sig = rand(1,fs);  
silence = zero(1,length(sig)');
sig = [sig;silence];    
wavplay(sig',fs,'async'); 
y = wavrecord(length(sig),fs,2);
```

The following code is what I came up with to calculate the distance:

```
x1 = y(:,1);
x2 = y(:,2);
[correlation,lags]=xcorr(x1,x2);  
delay_samples = lags(find(correlation==max(correlation)));  
speed = 343; % speed of sound is 343 m/s 
Ts=1/fs;  
time=delay_samples*Ts;
distance = speed/time;
```

when I run this, I get a distance, but I'm not sure if its correct!
IS MY METHOD RIGHT OR WRONG?

Answer (score 2):

As you've worded it, your calculation will not produce the absolute spatial distance between the two microphones. It will, rather, calculate the relative difference between the distances between the speaker and each microphone.

As a thought experiment, consider two microphones initially placed right next to each other. Since the sound from the speaker arrives at both mics at the same time, your formula will say the distance between the two mics is 0. Now, begin moving the two microphones away from each other along a line tangential to the speaker. The two mics remain equidistant from the speaker, and thus the sound from the speaker arrives at both mics at the same time (and thus your formula says they are right next to each other).

Answer (score 1):

To add to [MusiGenesis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7882842/1714410)' answer, it's not (just) that your calculation wouldn't yield the distance - the thought experiment depicted there actually shows that there is no way to calculate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you place both mics in the same straight line from the speaker you should be able to use your formula.

For example
Mic 1 at 1meter distance and mic 2 right behind it but at 3meter.